# copying from mutliple sources to multiple destinations using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

Is it possible to copy files from multiple sources to multiple destinations using powershell? I have researched a lot, but couldn't find any solution for this. The information of these multiple sources and destinations is in a SQL table. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give an advice on how to approach?

I have the data populated in the datatable with the below code. Now I want to use the data in the datatable which contains the source and destination locations and run the copy

```
$dataSource = “.\SQLEXPRESS”
$user = “user”
$pwd = “1234”
$database = “Test”
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd;Database=$database;Integrated Security=False;”

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$connection.Open()

$query = “SELECT * FROM Source&destinationinfo”

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)
```

The data in the table `[Source&destinationinfo]` is as follows:

```
 SourceLocation        DestinationLocation
 \\abc\test\           \\def\test\
 \\ghi\test\           \\jkl\test\
```

Comment: You can run a loop in which take first row, make `copy-item` then next etc

Comment: @gofr1 can you please share a sample code on how this can be done using copy-item?

Comment: `copy-item \\abc\test\* \\def\test\ ` that will copy all files from `\\abc\test\ ` to `\\def\test\ `. More info here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on SQL side:

1. Create Stored Procedure that will take data from tables and create a script.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.create_a_script_and_write_to_file
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @x nvarchar(max),
            @filename nvarchar(max) = 'D:\file.ps1'

    --here we generate script and put in @x
    SELECT @x = STUFF((
    SELECT top 5 'copy-item -Path "'+ PathFrom + '" -Destination "' + PathWhere + '" '
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,0,'')


    --here we write @x in file
    DECLARE @FSO int
    DECLARE @hr int
    DECLARE @src varchar(255)
    DECLARE @desc varchar(255)
    DECLARE @oFile int


    -- Create OLE Automation Object
    EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FSO OUT
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
       SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
        RETURN
    END 

    -- Create the XML file
    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @FSO, 'CreateTextFile', @oFile OUT, @filename, 8 , True
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
       SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
        RETURN
    END

    EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @oFile, 'Write', NULL, @x
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
       EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
       SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
        RETURN
    END

    -- Clear used objects
    EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @FSO
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
      EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
      SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
       RETURN
    END
    EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @oFile
    IF @hr <> 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @oFile, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
        SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
         RETURN
    END 

END
```

2. Create Job.

First step will be `EXEC dbo.create_a_script_and_write_to_file`, next step will be with type *Operating system (CmdExec)*: `powershell.exe -File "D:\file.ps1"`

After running this job - all files from `PathFrom` column of your table will be moved to `PathWhere`.